# TableLayoutPanel Labels Snap To Top Left?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel and every time I put a label into one of the cells, it snaps to the top left corner.  How can I get to it not do this or change where it snaps.

Also, is it possible to change a specific cell's background color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Soo, you can control where a label 'snaps' in a cell by setting the Dock property on the label. It will dock within the confines of the cell. I don't believe you can change the background color of a cell. One way to work around this is to put a panel in each cell, set it to dock using the full cell, and set the back ground color of the panel.

Comment: Is it possible to stick more than 1 lable in a cell?  I seem to be unable to do so...

Comment: @Soo - I've never tried, but off-hand, I don't see why not. It might be easier to put a panel in a cell, and then put multiple controls on the panel.

Comment: @sooprise, no you cannot, you need to add another container to the panel, then add controls to that container.

Comment: Its not the dock. Its the anchor. In this case you have to set it to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

To change the location of a control in a cell use the control's Anchor property.

To change the background color of a cell within a TableLayoutPanel, use the control's CellPaint event to test which Column and/or Row is being painted and set the color accordingly.

The following will set the background color of the cell at 1, 1 to red:

```
    private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Column == 1 && e.Row == 1) {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.CellBounds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to stick more than 1 lable in a cell?  I seem to be unable to do so...

Comment: @Soo I like Randy's suggestion: put all the controls you want in a Panel and then put the Panel in your TLP.

Answer (score 0):

@Jay Riggs has the answer. To slightly explain on it:

I've had this trouble. I dont think .Dock would do the trick. In my case, I have been successful by setting

```
            lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None; // to center the label. causes empty left space.
            // OR
            lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left // label sticks to left of the container and hence looks neatly aligned along with other controls.
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the anchor property is a better solution than dock normally.  You can also use the margin property to adjust the position of a label within a cell.  It's useful to set the top margin of a lable to 6 or so if you need it to line up with textboxes in the same row.

I can state categorically that you cannot put more than one control in a cell.  Do as others have suggested and add your labels to a panel then add the panel to the cell.  Flowlayout panels can be good for that, just don't overdo it or things will get very messy.

Answer (score 0):

First set `AutoSize` property of label to `False`.
Then set `TextAlign` property as you desire. It won't span to top left again.

Answer (score 0):

By using Dock and TextAlign Property of label you can set label Text on required place in tablelayoutpanel